# Microsoft Visual Studio | Load multiple Form in one panel [with passcode verification]

Tags: visual-studio

This is my first time making this and I want help on this. I want to know how to open the form in one panel. I manage to load the form in the panel but the thing is one of my tab seems like have a problem. This Tab is with passcode protected before it opens. Once you input the correct passcode, it view the form separately and not view in the panel. What should I do? how to fix this? please help me. Thanks in Advance!

Here's my code for passcode form:

```
        private void dash_pass_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dash_report_txtpass.Text == "himaru")
            {
                reports form2 = new reports();
                form2.Show();
                this.Hide();
                
            }
            else
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Please Enter Correct Passcode!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

This, my code for the main panel:

```
        public void loadform(object Form)
        { 
            if (this.main_panel.Controls.Count > 0) 
                this.main_panel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            Form f = Form as Form;
            f.TopLevel = false;
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.main_panel.Controls.Add(f);
            this.main_panel.Tag = f;
            f.Show();
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadform(new dash_report());
        }

        private void inv_list_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadform(new inventory());
        }
```

[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQtqY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUVR.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoehE.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srN1D.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imhdt.jpg)

I just want to view some tab with passcode before viewing in the main panel. But what I did was yes with a passcode but it's not viewing in the main panel.